# Changing a table to a temporary table - php/mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I have created the table that I want and how I want it. I have just realised I want to it to destroy upon session_destroy().

I know I can do this easily with `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`. When i edit the following code by adding `TEMPORARY` the table isnt created. It is created when `TEMPORARY` is not present.

```
$sep = '';

$sql = "CREATE TABLE `".$unique_id."`(";

$sql.= PHP_EOL;

$sql.= "`Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,".$sep;

foreach ($year_range as $year) {

  //ADD SEPERATOR BETWEEN LINES
  if ($year != end($year_range)) {
      $sep = ',';
  } else {
      $sep = '';
  }

  $sql.= "`".$year."` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL".$sep;
}
$sql.= PHP_EOL;
$sql.=')';
```

I've added the `TEMPORARY` in and it doesnt register nor create the table. Can anyone shed any light on what I might be doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the user connecting to the server has `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES` authority? It is separate from `CREATE`.

Comment: Im literally learning about it now. I just dont quite understand it. So they dont work in the same way then? All i really want from that TEMPORARY is to be able to delete it on session_destroy(). This is fine with a normal table, right? Thank you

Comment: Not sure what you mean by don't work the same way. A different permission is required to create temporary tables. Connect to the server and run `SHOW GRANTS` to see if the connected user has the necessary authority.

Comment: Why do you want/need to dynamically create tables? Why do they need to be destroyed on session destroy? Tables created this way are generally indacative of poor database structure. It also makes it much harder to prevent SQL Injection, because table names cannot be inserted via prepared statements meaning you need to maintain a list of allowed tables to be safe.

Comment: Iiterally for the user whilst on the site. Not required afterwards. To create a timeline. "Generally"  is correct. But not in this case.

Comment: This is starting to sound an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: I understand my mistake now. Ill use a regular table. You are grumpy

Comment: @JackB Why not just create a single table with an identifier for the user and delete the rows from the table when they are no longer needed? I'm just trying to say there is probably a better way that you can do this that is all around safer, easier to program and maintain.

Comment: I have the table name based on a timestamp + random. So each table is different. Avoiding collision for multiple users. I must admit my work is mainly work around but im trying to find the best ways possible and i really appreciate this community.

Comment: @JackB I said it's generally poor structure because I'm not trying to say what you are doing is definitely poor structure, I was really trying to understand why/what you were doing. I'm not sure if "_You are grumpy_" was meant to be an insult, I wasn't trying to come off as rude or mad. "_So each table is different. Avoiding collision for multiple users._" - This wouldn't be necessary at all if you just had 1 table. "_I must admit my work is mainly work around but im trying to find the best ways possible_" - Well, dynamically generated tables are almost certaintly _not_ the best possible way.

Comment: Sorry. I didnt mean to be rude. Thank you so much for your help. I dont know how to use one table as the data will be completely different for each user and there will be multiple users on the site at any time.The timeline is based on years. From a start to a finish. And is created with those specific years set for that user. Sorry if im not making sense. XY indeed

Comment: This i why I thought a temporary table would fix this. each to their own. and delete on destroy. I thought this was logical

Comment: @JackB Are the columns themselves different each time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219707/discussion-between-jackb-and-grumpycrouton).

Comment: Temporary tables are not related to PHP sessions. The temporary table is only accessible from the same database connection that created them. Every time you call `mysqli_connect()` or `new PDO` you get a new database connection, and will not be able to access temp tables from a previous connection.

Comment: Thats very clear. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of dynamically creating tables like this, you should look into better uses of [relational databases](https://aws.amazon.com/relational-database/).

I think you just need 2 tables with a [One to Many](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561) relationship

Something like this setup should work:

```
Table 1: User - basically a replacement for multiple dynamic tables. Stores an identifer for the user of the site.
Columns: unique_id (auto increment) | user (user identifier)

Table 2: years - contains a row for each year
Columns: unique_id (auto increment) | users_identifier (unique_id from users table) | year | stages_match
```

This utilizes something called a ["foreign key"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Basically, it means "this row belongs to the unique_id from another table"

You can get rid of the data the same way you delete the table now; when the user ends their session, delete all of the rows in the user table belonging to that user. If you set up the foreign key right, this would also remove all of the rows for that user from the years table.

Comment: Thank you. Have learned a lot today @GrumpyCrouton. You're not so grumpy after all. :)